# Возможно ли в blade.php провести проверку Auth::check

Tags: php, laravel

Только начинаю изучать laravel. Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли как то в blade.php проверить авторизован пользователь или нет. Если нет то каким образом сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Продолжайте [изучать](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives).

Comment: Спасибо, большое, но так же нужно как то вытащить имя пользователя

Comment: @Виталий `{{ auth()->user()->some_column }}` [auth()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-auth)